# Node.js- Add new field in array of Mongodb object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a collection of users that has an array of multiple plates :

```
users : [
{
_id: '61234XXX'
plates: [
 {
   _id: '123'
   'color': 'orange'
 },
 {
   _id: '124'
   'color': 'blue'
 }
]
},
{
_id: '63456XXX'
plates: [
 {
   _id: '321'
   'color': 'orange'
 },
 {
   _id: '432'
   'color': 'green'
 }
]
}
]
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to add a new field to the all current plate objects for every user:

I've got to this:

```
  await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: '63456XXX' },
      {
        $set : {
          [`plates.0.plateStyle`]: "testValue"
        }
      }
  )
```

Tho this works it's not fit for purpose. Is there a better way I can iterate over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

Here you are using [array filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to tell mongo: "Where you find an object with `_id: "61234XXX"` and `exists the plates` then, there, get the document (`elem`) which match that `plates` is not empty (to get all) and add `plateStyle`".

```js
await User.updateMany({
  _id: "61234XXX",
  plates: {
    $exists: true
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "plates.$[elem].plateStyle": "testValue"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      elem: { $ne: [ "$plates", [] ] }
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HflwNrQKSip)

Also if you are finding by `_id` you won't need `updateMany` since `_id` is unique and only will be 1 or 0 results.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time!

unfortunately that doesn't work, the example you shared only shows it updating the first object in the array

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the trick is to use array filters.

Comment: Thanks! 

If you could, could you explain whats happening here?


{
      elem: {
        $ne: [
          "$_id",
          null
        ]
      }


the $ne onwards has thrown me off and can't find its ref in the docs

Comment: [$ne](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) is "not equal". Here is used to match all documents which `_id` is **not equal** to `null`. Also in the link I've used `$ne: ["$plates",[]]` which I think is better. This is to match all elements where exists the array `plates`. What is basically you want, if exists the array, update the element.